# How to create a setup installer in Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, installshield

I have an application in python which requires:

1. copy specific folder to ProgramFiles
2. run an exe file which installs some dependencies
3. set a path variable (or run a command which does that)
4. create a shortcut on desktop

I tried installShield but found out that it cannot start another installer on the way. Any Ideas on how to easily create a simple Wizzard installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easily done with every installer creation tools like InstallShield, Advanced Installer, etc. which have support for installing file and shortcuts, prerequisites packages (your EXE) and setting path variables.